# What's the effective risk of using deprecated methods on Android platform?

Tags: android, deprecated

I created a project using an old version of Android (2.2). Now I refreshed the project and I'm using the last version (4.x). I see a lot of warnings about method deprecation, for example: `addPreferencesFromResource()`.

What is the effective risk on perpetuating the use of `addPreferencesFromResource()` in my code?

Comment: you never know the consequences of using a deprecated method. :)

Comment: My question is specific for the Android platform, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Seraphim Android uses the java code as you know... thats why I marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major risk is if Google stops the support for the deprecated methods in future version of their OS/firmware, your app which is based on deprecated methods will have undefined behaviour / it won't run at all. Note that the reason a company deprecates some methods/classes is either because of bugs/a better alternative exists.

Answer (score 1):

You simply risk one thing : if google deprecates the api, it means it will not be maintained. Perhaps not immediatly, but one day you may be using something that doesn't fully work or didn't receive latest bug fixes.